# UIcollection view bug of selecting more than one cells at a time

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

I am creating a calendar of 7 day. I am using a collection view with 7 cells but when i select the very last cell of the collection view and scroll to the first one, the last cell remains selected and the first cell also gets selected. Here are the screenshot of the bug i am getting. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqDjU.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i78vx.png)
**Here is the code in my main view controller**

```
   `import UIKit
    import Foundation

    class ScheduleViewController: UIViewController {
        let top = UIColor(red: 217/255, green: 30/255, blue: 133/255, alpha: 1)
        let bottom = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 56/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
        let todayColor = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 56/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
        //    let otherDayColor = UIColor(red: 90/255, green: 90/255, blue: 90/255, alpha: 1)
        let otherDayColor = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 56/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
        var now = Date()
        var day = DateFormatter()


        let dateHeading: UILabel = {
            let heading = UILabel()
            heading.text = "Date"
            heading.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 20)
            heading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            heading.numberOfLines = 0
            heading.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            return heading
        }()
        fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            cv.backgroundColor = .clear
            cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cv.register(CalendarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellID")
            return cv
        }()

        let bookButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.setTitle("Book", for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 22)
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            return button
        }()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            view.backgroundColor = .black
            setupNavigationBar()
            view.addSubview(bookButton)
            bookButtonLayout()
            view.addSubview(collectionView)
            collectionViewLayout()
            configureCollectionView()
            collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
            view.addSubview(dateHeading)
            dateHeadingLayout()
            let gradientWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.colors = [top.cgColor, bottom.cgColor]
            gradientLayer.locations = [0.15, 1]
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gradientWidth, height: 44)
            gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 5
            bookButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        }


        func myCalender(numDay: Int) -> Date {
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.setValue(numDay, for: .day); // +1 day

            let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: now)

            return tomorrow!
        }

        func setupNavigationBar(){
            self.navigationItem.title = "Schedule"
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        }

        func collectionViewLayout(){
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85).isActive = true
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

        }

        func configureCollectionView(){
            collectionView.delegate = self
            collectionView.dataSource = self

        }

        func dateHeadingLayout(){
            dateHeading.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26).isActive = true
            dateHeading.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42).isActive = true
            dateHeading.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
            dateHeading.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        }


        func bookButtonLayout(){
            bookButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
            bookButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
            bookButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            bookButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
        }
    }
    extension ScheduleViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: 70, height: 75)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 7
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarCell
            if cell?.isSelected == true{
                cell?.backgroundColor = todayColor
                cell?.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)
                cell?.dayLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)
                cell?.isOpaque = false
            }
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarCell
            if cell?.isSelected == false{
                cell?.backgroundColor = .clear
                cell?.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
                cell?.dayLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
                cell?.isOpaque = false
            }
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCell
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            cell.dayLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            cell.isOpaque = false

            if cell.isSelected == true{
                cell.backgroundColor = todayColor
                cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)
                cell.dayLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)
                cell.isOpaque = false
            }

            if indexPath.row == 0{
                cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()) - 1])
                cell.dateLabel.text = now.string(format: "dd")
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 1{
                cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 1)) - 1])
                cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 1).string(format: "dd")
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 2{
                cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 2)) - 1])
                cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 2).string(format: "dd")
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 3{
                cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 3)) - 1])
                cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 3).string(format: "dd")
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 4{
                cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 4)) - 1])
                cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 4).string(format: "dd")
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 5{
                cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 5)) - 1])
                cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 5).string(format: "dd")
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 6{
                cell.dayLabel.text = (day.shortWeekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myCalender(numDay: 6)) - 1])
                cell.dateLabel.text = myCalender(numDay: 6).string(format: "dd")
            }
            cell.isSelected = (cellStatus[indexPath.row] as? Bool) ?? false
            return cell
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 5
        }


    }
    extension Date {
        func string(format: String) -> String {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.timeZone = .current
            formatter.dateFormat = format
            formatter.shortWeekdaySymbols = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
            return formatter.string(from: self)
        }
    }`
```

**And here is my code for the custom calendar cell**

```
`import UIKit
class CalendarCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let dateLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 30)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()

    let dayLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 20)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        contentView.addSubview(dayLabel)
        dayLabelLayout()
        contentView.addSubview(dateLabel)
        dateLabelLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func dateLabelLayout(){
        dateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        dateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        dateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        dateLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dayLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func dayLabelLayout(){
        dayLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        dayLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        dayLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        dayLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true


    }

}
`
```

Comment: Did you get a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

that cell is reused not selected ... but due to reuse ... its backgroundColor , dateLabel , dayLabel and isOpaque changed

In your `CalendarCell` .. override this function with default values which is of non selected cell ..

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        backgroundColor = .white//defaultValue
        dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1) // default value
        cell?.dayLabel.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1) // default value
        cell?.isOpaque = false // default value
    }
```

Comment: do not ever! forget call super!
super.prepareForReuse()